# Exiftool batch update not working

Tags: batch-processing, exif, exiftool

There are two folders with images in them and the filenames of the images are identical.

I'd like to copy the exif data of the images from one folder to another. Exiftool seems to be the perfect tool to do this job. According to the documentation this command should work:

`exiftool -TagsFromFile ../../temp/source/%d%f.JPG -all:all -ext JPG ../../temp/target`

The console even returns this:

`1 directories scanned
17 image files updated`

However when I check the results the source and target file exif datas are different.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you give an example of what's different? That command looks correct.